# Can we send NSString Value between devices connected via bluetooth, Using Game Center

Tags: nsstring, bluetooth, send

Can we send NSString Value between devices connected via Bluetooth, using Game Center?

Here is some part of my code:

```
typedef enum {
    messageType1 = 0;
    messageType2 = 1;
}
messageType;

typedef struct {
    MessageType messageType;
    NSString *myName;
} MyMessage;
```

And In my Class I have this method to send the message:

```
 MyMessage myMessage;
 myMessage.messageType = messageType2;
 myMessage.myName = @"ABCDEFGH";
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&myMessage length:sizeof(MyMessage)];
 [self sendDataToAllPeers:data withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:error];
```

to receive data I have method:

```
-(void) receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession: (GKSession *)session context:(void *)context{
    MyMessage myMessage = *((MyMessage *) [data bytes]);
    type = myMessage.messageType;
    name = myMessage.myName;
}
```

**Question:** How can I get `myName` ? (I am able to get `MessageType`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send NSData as Archived NSArray:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myMessage.messageType, myMessage.myName, nil];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
[self sendDataToAllPeers:data];
```

Receive NSData and Unarchive to NSArray:

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];
type = [array objectAtIndex:0];
name = [array objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Thanks ILYA2606. Your answer is right, but it is not working in my app., because I am sending data in form of Struct and Enum as shown in my code. I can not send it in form of NSArray(because data is too large, it will affect on performance of my app. for example MessageType is messageType1,messageType2,....messageType20 and myMessage contains too many things. There are some more Struct with MessageType). 
At Receiver End I am using 
if(type = myMessage->messageType)
{perform some task, like print myName}

I need to send Data in same format as shown.
Now, How can I get MyName(NSString)